# java Spring, autowired singleton components and performance

Tags: java, spring, concurrency, singleton, autowired

Our java spring app exposes a Rest API and is fairly typical

It is build in layers:

1. RestController classes
2. Service classes
3. Repository classes
4. oracle DB

Those layers use the annotation @RestController, @Service, etc. with @Autowired to access the lower level.

Now, all those end up being singletons. But since there is no state, it should not be a problem.. Multiple requests can proceed concurrently using the same singletons objects (in different threads of execution). At least, that's my understanding.

Now, for one of our new Rest API endpoints, we have to call a third party API, so the datapath will be like this:

1. RestController
2. Service
3. CustomRestClient
4. third party server somewhere

In CustomRestClient, there is an @Autowired RestTemplate instance. Because everything is a singleton, this rest_template will be one as well.
Now i checked and it is thread-safe so it should work without any concurrency access exception. However I wonder:

Will that constitute a bottleneck, all parallel requests having to wait to use this one shared RestTemplate?  with some internal locks or something? How to make sure no thread has to wait?

(btw one reason rest_template is autowired is to help with mock unit testing)

I guess my question is more about how to make sure this Spring singleton architecture can serve lots of parallel requests even when one layer has to use an injected object that may have state?  And if that's impossible and that object has to be instantiated with "new", how can we still unit-test the class using the mock approach?

Comment: You said yourself that RestTemplate is thread-safe. Why do you think all parallel requests would have to wait? to use the shared RestTemplate? Being thread-safe means that it can be used concurrently, by several threads.

Comment: There are different ways to make a class thread safe, maybe it is thread-safe with lots of 'synchronised' private functions inside it. Maybe it is thread-safe in the sense that it will not crash when used concurrently but to achieve that, it has been designed in a way that makes it slower in a multithreading context. In that case instantiating one per request/thread could give faster performances.

Comment: Fortunately, that's not the case.

Comment: Maybe, the question should focus on using @ Autowired for a class (any) that is not thread-safe or is 'slow in a multithreading context". How to @ autowire something but get a new instance every time because it is not good at multithreading?

Comment: Several techniques are described here: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-scopes-sing-prot-interaction and here: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-scopes-other-injection

Comment: @JBNizet since you are talking about concurrency can you answer me in this question : if we have a wrapper class that applies the singleton pattern to wrap a data source and this wapper class gas method getConnetion that initialize the dataSource if it is null should we add to this method keyword synchronized and why ?

Comment: @achabahe yes, otherwise multiple threads might invoke the method concurrently, and thus initialize two data sources rather than 1. But the singleton pattern is an anti-pattern.

Comment: if it is anti-pattern how would you think of solving . spring uses singleton , i wonder how they implement it

Comment: @JBNizet i apreciate your answer

Comment: They implementing it by injecting always the same instance. Not by restricting the number of instances that can be created, and making it globally available using a static getInstance() method like the singleton "pattern" does.